# Find the specific consecutive set of numbers in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I want to find a number of times an integer occurs consecutively in an array. I have found one example doing something similar:

```
const numbers = [0,0,0,296,296,0,0,296,296,296,0,0,0,0,0,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293];

let chunks = [];

let prev = 0;
numbers.forEach((current) => {
  if ( current - prev != 1 ) chunks.push([]);

  // Now we can add our number to the current chunk!
  chunks[chunks.length - 1].push(current);
  prev = current;
});

chunks.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

console.log('Longest consecutive set:', chunks[0]);
console.log('Size of longest consecutive set:', chunks[0].length);
```

I just want to get the number of longest consecutive of `0`, like:

```
result: {
  key: 0
  longestConsecutive: 5
}
```

Any good solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like the following:

```js
const numbers = [0,0,0,296,296,0,0,296,296,296,0,0,0,0,0,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,91];

function findConsecCount(value) {
  
  var startIndex = -1
  var result = 0
  
  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    
    if(numbers[i] === value) {
      if(startIndex === -1) {
        startIndex = i
      }
    }
    
    if(numbers[i] !== value) {
      if(startIndex !== -1) {
        result = Math.max(result, i - startIndex)
        startIndex = -1;
      }
    }
  }
      
  if(numbers[numbers.length - 1] === value) {
    if(startIndex !== -1) {
      result = Math.max(result, i - startIndex)
      startIndex = -1;
    }
  }
  
  return {
    key : value, 
    longestConsecutive : result
  }
}

console.log( findConsecCount(0) )
console.log( findConsecCount(293) )
console.log( findConsecCount(296) )
console.log( findConsecCount(91) )
```

Comment: @YukwongTsang you're welcome - glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an array of sequence lengths for your target value and then use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to get the largest value in that array (which is the length of the longest sequence):

```js
const numbers = [0,0,0,296,296,0,0,296,296,296,0,0,0,0,0,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293];

function max_consecutive ( arr, value ) {
  return Math.max( ...numbers.reduce( (sequence_lengths, x) => {
      x === value ? sequence_lengths[0]++ : sequence_lengths.unshift(0);
      return sequence_lengths;
    }, [0]
  ) );
}

console.log( max_consecutive(  numbers, 0 ) );
console.log( max_consecutive(  numbers, 1 ) );
console.log( max_consecutive(  numbers, 293 ) );
console.log( max_consecutive(  numbers, 296 ) );
```

Comment: Great solution. There's a typo in the example - you take `arr` as argument but work with `numbers` in the function body.

Answer (score 2):

You can also group "chunk" lengths by key using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and then [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them for each key:

```js
const numbers = [0, 0, 0, 296, 296, 0, 0, 296, 296, 296, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293];

let consecutiveGroups = numbers.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
  if (!(curr in acc)) acc[curr] = [];
  if (arr[i - 1] != curr) acc[curr].push(1);
  else acc[curr][acc[curr].length - 1] += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

Object.values(consecutiveGroups)
      .forEach(g => g.sort((a, b) => b - a));

console.log(consecutiveGroups);
console.log('longest consecutive 0s', consecutiveGroups[0][0]);
console.log('longest consecutive 296s', consecutiveGroups[296][0]);
```

*[The update to using lengths instead of arrays of numbers was inspired by @Paulpro's fantastic solution]*

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this might be a case where a simple `while` loop is the easiest to understand and should be quite quick. This just runs two indexes up the array keeping track of the longest sequence found:

```js
const numbers = [0, 0, 0, 296, 296, 0, 0, 296, 296, 296, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293];


function longestConsecutive(searchedFor, numbers) {
  let start = stop = longest = 0

  while (start < numbers.length + 1) {
    if (numbers[start] !== searchedFor) {
      longest = start - stop > longest ? start - stop : longest
      stop = start + 1
    }
    start++
  }
  return longest
}

console.log(longestConsecutive(0, numbers))
console.log(longestConsecutive(296, numbers))
console.log(longestConsecutive(293, numbers))
```